# being mocked vs mocked after a noun

Tags: past-participles

In the sentence:

To please others, people being mocked or teased may suppress their actual feelings which can result in stress to him.

what if I change it to

To please others, people mocked or teased may suppress their actual feelings which can result in stress to him.

Which one is more correct?

I give another example:

"Remind students not to be too worried when encountering sexual health problems."

I wonder if it is better to say "when they encounter". My question is whether such use of participle phrase is only ambiguous or incorrect at all.

Comment: The reduced relative clause may give rise to a garden-path reading. This is the case with the second variant, though not the first (and not the unreduced 'To please others, people who are [regularly?] being mocked or teased may suppress their actual feelings ...').

Comment: I would probably say "... people *who* are mocked or teased ..."

Comment: And perhaps "... actual feelings, with resulting stress", or maybe "... actual feelings, resulting in increased stress."

Answer (score 2):

First one is better, but neither is incorrect.

Consider also:

- When mocked or teased, people may . . . .

(edit)
Charon is correct about "to him" being wrong. I might suggest changing
"result in stress to him." to "cause themselves stress."

Oh, and there really should be a comma after "feelings".

Comment: I think many of you misunderstood my question, including those who said my question is off-topic. My question concerns the correct form of participle (whether past participle or being + past participle) after nouns. No one except Edwin points it out here.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is better, but neither is correct because you have moved from plural to singular.

Observe:

*"**People** being mocked or teased may .... which can result in stress to **him**"*

You need to change the latter word in bold to a plural. Like so:

*"**People** being mocked or teased may .... which can result in stress to **themselves**"*